# How to cut an entire line in SAP Web IDE

Tags: sap-web-ide

I'm used to using Sublime Text and I constantly use `Ctrl-x` to remove entire lines. In SAP Web IDE `Ctrl-x` only works on selected text.

Is there anyway to add this to SAP Web IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> to delete the line
- <kbd>Alt + ↑↓</kbd> to move the line